# Starting npm start with docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Hi I'm running a basic react project with npm and I'm trying to start it in a docker container.  However I can't actually get the project to run.  My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:7.8.0


WORKDIR /

ADD . /


EXPOSE 80


RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm run start
```

I get the relevant message saying that the project can now be viewed but in the browser nothing shows up.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What command are you using to run docker container?

Comment: First docker build -t myapp .  then docker run -p 6000:80 myapp

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure in your app you are running the server at `80` port and in your browser you are hitting `6000` port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your ports might be backwards in your `docker run` command. If you are running your react app on port 6000, and want to expose this to the outside on port 80, then you should run your container with ...

`docker run -p 80:6000 myapp`

Usage: `docker run -p <HOST_PORT>:<CONTAINER_PORT> <APP_NAME>`

Answer (score 1):

Solved a similar issue by modifying npm start into package.json (line 6).

Try to add **--host 0.0.0.0** after ng serve.

`"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",`

In last result, debug with `curl http://localhost:6000`

It might be called a websocket issue